# How to show "number of foo: number" in jquery tooltip using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, tooltip

I want to show "number of participants: 10" in jquery tooltip using ajax. 
There are a few participants for each event in my DB.

So in my JS file:

```js
function tooltip(self){
        $("#tt").tooltip({
            content: function(){
                var eventID = $(this).data('js');
                console.log(eventID);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/participants/'+eventID+'/number',
                    // data: {should I do something here?},
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#tt').attr('title', data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
}
```

and the ajax url connected to this function:

```php
    public function participantsNumber(int $event_id)
    {
        $num = Participant::find($event_id)->toArray();
        echo count($num);
    }
```

So actually it's working, however the tooltip shows number of columns. 
I want to show how many participants with that `$event_id`. 
In this tooltip form like:

```
num of participants: data
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the value/structure of `$num`?

Comment: Your tooltip just shows whatever you return from the server side.  Change the server-side code to return the correct text/value, nothing to do with jquery/ajax.

Comment: @Hix Oh I see, it looked like `array:6 [▼
  "event_id" => 3
  "id" => 2
  "name" => "people1"
  "date" => "2019-09-04"
  "created_at" => "2019-08-05 06:50:03"
  "updated_at" => "2019-08-30 05:23:30"` this. it just found one participant who has that event_id, while i thought it was num of participants.

Answer (score 0):

@freedomn-m 
you're right it's fixed with this code:

```php
    public function participantsNumber(int $event_id)
    {
        $num = Participant::all();
        echo "number of participants: ".$num->where("event_id", $event_id)->count();
    }
```